# Bug on the review web page?

Tags: feature-request, bug, design, review-page

Recently I recognized a change of the behaviour of the review pages. Now after opening an question in the first post queue to be reviewed you see all three buttons enlighted:

[image]

For me astonishing is that button `I'm done` is activated at once.  It should be activated after a done review, for example upvoting or editing ...

One other pages there is the old behaviour ...

Is that a bug or missed I something?

Comment: I have not experienced the "I'm done" active without actually reviewing...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been updated to something that clearly reflects the possibilities available to the reviewer; an updated mouse icon as well:

[image]

[image]

---

Yes, please change this. The following highlights some of the visual problems:

- "No Action Needed" is *inactive*, while "I'm Done" and "Skip" are *active*:

  [image]

  [image]

  The differences are barely visible, even on mouse-over (apart from the icon change).
- The only discernment between *active* and *inactive* seems to be a mildly visible blackened border and a slight change in the tone of redness upon mouse-over.

  "No Action Needed" and "Skip" are *active*, while "I'm Done" is *inactive*:

  [image]
- An interactive view:

  [image]